# Crossfade effect with carousel not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, caroufredsel

I have two caroufredsel sliders with the same effect:

the first slider where on the homepage doesn't cross fade
http://www.clubseekr.com

however on another page where the same slider is used with same effect it does work
http://clubseekr.com/tokyo/unit/
In order to go to the slider just click on one of the 4 photos underneath the heading: Photos

In order to get it with the desired crossfade effect I use the following code

```
$('#carousel').carouFredSel({ 
    scroll : { fx : "crossfade" }
});
```

The total code  is a bit more than that but this should give the effect as well on the homepage.
Is there something i am doing wrong in the slider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most probably you have a Hero-rotating bar in your home page and that JavaScript functions conflict with your carousel  JavaScript functions. if i faced this problem i will get any one of those parts to another page and join it using Iframe. when you use Iframe those java functions can work on both of them separately without any collisions.

Comment: thanks! i havent thought of that. I am going to try some things